# Trigger is not firing using Reference

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures

I am writing one trigger that will fire on update and insert on one table and insert into another table. Trigger looks like this.

```
create or replace trigger update_test_history
  before insert or update on demo.test_req REFERENCING NEW AS NEW OLD AS old
  for each row
declare
  v_count number(1);
begin

     if :old.quote_request_id != null then
       --Update History table
       insert into demo.test_req_history
         (history_id,
          req_id)
       values
         (isisdba.req_hist_seq.nextval,
          :old.req_id);
      end if;

end update_test_history;
```

This trigger is not working on DML. But if i remove the if condition then it start working. 
Can someone please tell me whats wrong with this. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Define "not working"?  `null` is never equal to any value including `null`.  `null` is also never unequal to another value including `null`.  So `something != null` will never evaluate to `true`.  Perhaps you want `:old.quote_request_id is not null`.

Comment: Thanks Jastin, Its is working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`null` is never equal to any value including `null`. `null` is also never unequal to another value including `null`. So the statement

```
if( <<some expression>> != null )
then
  <<do something>>
end if;
```

will ever get into the `<<do something>>` block.  Neither will

```
if( <<some expression>> = null )
then
  <<do something>>
end if;
```

You have to use ternary logic where you are dealing with `null` values bu saying `is null` or `is not null`.  It appears that you probably want

```
if( :old.quote_request_id is not null )
the
  <<do something>>
end if;
```